# Is there a way to integrate stencil components into frameworks locally without publishing to NPM?

Tags: javascript, npm, stenciljs

I am currently testing stencil js. For now I want to write stencil components and include them within a VUE/React project. The official website of stencil already shows how to integrate them within a framework (https://stenciljs.com/docs/overview). But they assume that your own stencil component library has already been published to npm.

***Is there a way to integrate stencil components locally into a framework to test them without publishing them first?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) for that.

```sh
cd my-component-lib
npm link

cd ../my-app
npm link my-component-lib # or whatever you have named the project in package.json
```

If you have any problems with that (e. g. with paths not resolving properly), you can also try to pack your package and install the packed version instead, using [npm-pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack.html):

```
cd my-component-lib
npm pack

cd ../my-app
npm install ../my-component-lib/my-component-lib-1.0.0.tgz
```

Linking is preferable though because changes to your component library will be reflected immediately (after a rebuild), whereas with packing you'd have to re-pack and re-install it after every change to your lib.

Comment: This also works for a Stencil component used in a different Stencil project.

Comment: `npm pack` worked for me in 2024

Answer (score 5):

Instead of publishing or packing your packages, you could utilize [TypeScript's path mapping feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

This allows you to write your import statements just as you would with a published package, but behind the scenes TypeScript maps the imports to their given source code location.

Here's an example of a tsconfig.json with path mapping added to the compiler options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "ui-components": ["libs/ui-components"],
      "ui-components/loader": ["libs/ui-components/dist/loader/index.cjs.js"],
      "ui-components-react": ["generated/ui-components-react/src/components.ts"]
    },
    ...
```

As you can see, it has 3 mappings: the path to the core Stencil components `ui-components`, the path to the generated React components which are exposed as `ui-components-react`, as well as the generated loader `ui-components/loader` which provides the bridge between the Custom elements and the React wrappers.

I created a full working example for Stencil Web Components with generated bindings and wrappers for React that comes without the need of publishing any package: [Nx Stencil React](https://github.com/Mobiletainment/Nx-Stencil-React).

Please note that this answer is based on `@stencil/core 1.14.0` or below. Future versions may have a different approach on generating the framework integrations.

Answer (score 3):

I've had quite a bit of trouble with this myself so will provide an answer specifically for Vue 3 as Stencil's [Framework Integrations](https://stenciljs.com/docs/vue) guide seems to refer only to Vue 2.

## Starting Projects

### Stencil Component

Following the [Getting Started](https://stenciljs.com/docs/getting-started) guide run `npm init stencil`. Choose the `component` option.

There was a bug in `v2.7.0` so I update to `v2.8.0` with `npm i @stencil/core@latest --save-exact`

Build the project with `npm run build`

#### Optional

By default, the stencil project configures multiple build targets, to make it easier to see what build files are being used you can edit the stencil config to only include the custom elements bundle:

```js
\\ stencil.config.ts
outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements-bundle',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
  ],
```

You also need the 'dist' type for the `.d.ts` typings file to be generated with your custom-elements (not sure why).

### Vue 3 App

Using a globally installed [Vue CLI](https://next.cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create) `@vue/cli@4.5.13` create a new Vue 3 default project.

## Using Stencil in Vue 3

Install your stencil component project
`npm install --save ../<path>/stencil-component` as a dependency of your vue app.

### Fixing NPM Module Resolution

Following the [Vue CLI - Troubleshooting](https://next.cli.vuejs.org/guide/troubleshooting.html) guide add a `vue.config.js` file to the root of your Vue 3 project with the line `config.resolve.symlinks(false),`

### Skipping Component Resolution

In the same file we need to configure [Using Custom Elements in View](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#skipping-component-resolution)

```js
\\ vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.symlinks(false),
        config.module
            .rule("vue")
            .use("vue-loader")
            .tap((options) => ({
                ...options,
                compilerOptions: {
                    isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes("my-"),
                },
            }));
    },
};
```

### Framework Integration

Now we can declare the custom elements, but in the Vue 3 way

```js
\\ main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import { defineCustomElements } from "stencil-component";

defineCustomElements();

createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

You can now use your custom component as normal. Here's what my `App.vue` file looked like after hacking the example starter code:

```js
<template>
    <my-component first="Andy" middle="2K" last="11"></my-component>
</template>

<script>
import { MyComponent } from "stencil-component";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

## Errors

### No ESLint Config

`No ESLint configuration found in /<path>/stencil-component/dist/custom-elements.`

Fixed by telling webpack not to resolve symlinks in `vue.config.js`

### Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'

This error occurs in the browser after a successful compilation.

Resolved by telling webpack / vue not to resolve your custom components

### Custom Component Not Visible

There are no errors and your component is showing in the DOM inspector but not appearing on the page.

You need to `defineCustomElements()` in `main.js`.

### Component not found

I've had some variation of this error when trying to import and use my component but haven't been able to reproduce it just now. Doing all of the above and restarting the dev server works fine for me.

Comment: hello does work well in vue3 by vite?

Comment: vue3 can not listen cutome event in stencil event.

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/2874#issuecomment-915384370) helps. I've not had chance to look myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

For local integration, you can reference the `esm.js` file inside `www/build` folder which can be used in the head tag of the Vue/React project.

For eg if you have the  below 2 apps

`stencil-components`  -  stencil components

`stencil-react` -  sample react app which will consume the components.

Once you run stencil-components by `npm run start` it will be hosted at 3333 (by default).
Including below line in head of`index.html` of `stencil-react` will integrate components with live reloading on change.

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:3333/build/stencil-components.esm.js"></script>
```